# Non-random sampling of point vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, sampling

I have a point vector layer with 47.000.000 points representing elevation. It is a regular grid with constant spacing. I aim for rasterization but it is very slow.
I know how to do random sampling but have not found a grid sampling. (not on this stack either)

How to create a more spaced grid, based on the initial layer's values?

Comment: What about to create a new point grid using the extension of the original one with the *Create Grid* algorithm and, then, using an ```aggregate``` expression or the *Join attribute by location* algorithm add the elevation data from the original grid?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Join Attribute worked as my new grid was perfectly over the old one so intersect matched the location.

Comment: Happy to listen that helps. I will write an proper answer so you can tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you can create a new point grid using the extension of the original one. YOu can use the *Create Grid* algorithm to do that.

Then, using an `aggregate` expression or the *Join attribute by location* algorithm you can add the elevation data from the original grid to the new layer.